# CORS ошибка при поптыке GET запроса с localhost

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

Есть get запрос на js через XMLHttpRequest

```
const xhr = новый XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open ('GET', 'https://pin-up.partners/api/kr0wc0oo7x/statisticGeneral');

// xhr.setRequestHeader ('Content-Type', 'application / json');

xhr.addEventListener ('load', () => {
     console.log (xhr.responseText);
});


xhr.send ();
```

разворачиваю это все через Live Server в vscode и получаю ошибку:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pin-up.partners/api/kr0wc0oo7x/statisticGeneral' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
GET https://pin-up.partners/api/kr0wc0oo7x/statisticGeneral net::ERR_FAILED
```

но при загрузке плагина Moesif CORS в браузер Chrome и его включении все работает нормально и запрос обрабатывается.

Вопрос: Как я могу исправить это из vscode и моего локального адреса без доп. расширения в браузере и продолжить разработку?
Большое спасибо за ответы ранее)

Comment: Никак. Совсем никак.

Comment: Обратиться к администратору сайта pin-up.partners чтобы он разрешил вашему сайту отправлять запросы к его сайту

Comment: @andreymal, открыто, с постмана все прекрасно достает, но вот с mamp или live server на vscode выдает ошибку CORS .

Comment: Читать что такое CORS до полного понимания